# How to use gnome with novnc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg, gnome, vnc

I am trying to use gnome with novnc, but I am getting a clock, logout button, accessibility button, and the ubuntu logo as the output

[Output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPYy7.png)

Heres my startup script:

```sh
Xvfb -ac :1 -screen 0 1366x768x16 &> /dev/null &
export DISPLAY=:1 &
DISPLAY=:1 gnome-shell --mode=gdm --sync &
x11vnc -geometry 1366x768 -nopw -localhost -display :1 &> /dev/null &
./novnc/utils/novnc_proxy --vnc localhost:5900 --listen localhost:6080
```

(I also have the gdm/gdm3 service running)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so after I was searching through stuff, I found out that I was running it with (sudo bash), instead of being in user root (sudo su), so once I changed to user root, it worked